# Disc light comes on when pressing keys in Iceweasel Preferences? Is this malevolent?

Tags: storage, iceweasel

On Linux,I'm using the Iceweasel web browser (it's effectively Firefox), and in
Edit/Preferences/General/Startup, when I type a URL into the "Home Page" box,
the hard disc light comes on for EVERY press of a key (eg www.google.com). This
seems odd (and unnecessary). I've tried entering text in other boxes in
Preferences, and the disc light DOESN'T come on.

Do you know why the disc light is coming on, and does it suggest that something
sneaky and malevolent is happening?

Answer (score 5):

### The short answer

No, it's probably not malevolent. It appears Iceweasel writes its preferences file after every keystroke.

### The long answer (how to find out)

The same thing happens here.

There is a way to determine exactly what's going on, by using the kernel's block-access dump feature. All of the below is done as root:

First, you need to stop the kernel logging daemon—otherwise, there will be lots of activity: writing the kernel log to disk. On my machine, it's part of rsyslog, so I do:

```
# /etc/init.d/rsyslog stop
[ ok ] Stopping enhanced syslogd: rsyslogd.
```

Now, in another terminal, `cat /proc/kmsg`. This will spit out the kernel logs, without writing them to disk.

Finally, `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump` to turn the block dump feature on. You should fairly quickly see output in the `cat` terminal, at least one line for each time the disk light blinks.

If there are far too many lines (there are here, because of a bunch of stuff running) you can use `grep` to filter them. E.g., you could use `grep 'dirtied inode' /proc/kmsg` or `grep iceweasel /proc/kmsg`

Then go ahead and type in the preferences box to see what disk activity there is. Once you've found out, run `echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump` to turn off the block dump, and start back up your kernel logger (`/etc/init.d/rsyslog start` here)

Here is what I got:

```
<7>[618256.942332] iceweasel(4055): dirtied inode 563662 (prefs-1.js) on dm-3
<7>[618256.946971] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 104158720 on dm-3 (280 sectors)
<7>[618256.946984] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sda3 (8 sectors)
<7>[618256.946988] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sdd3 (8 sectors)
<7>[618256.946991] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sdb3 (8 sectors)
<7>[618256.946994] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sdc3 (8 sectors)
<7>[618258.588306] iceweasel(4055): dirtied inode 563720 (prefs-1.js) on dm-3
<7>[618258.592806] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 104081920 on dm-3 (280 sectors)
<7>[618258.621531] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sda3 (8 sectors)
<7>[618258.621536] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sdd3 (8 sectors)
<7>[618258.621539] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sdb3 (8 sectors)
<7>[618258.621541] iceweasel(4055): WRITE block 1953005758 on sdc3 (8 sectors)
⋮
```

So, what's happening is that every time you type in that field, Iceweasel immediately writes it to the preferences file. Then, on my system, it passes through LVM (the dm-3 stuff) an becomes a physical write to 4 disks (due to mdraid).