# Does "syslogd" cause "cat /proc/kmsg" not to work properly?

Tags: proc, syslog

I'm using `cat /proc/kmsg` to determine which process and file was involved in
certain disc writes. I'm using the method given in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108598/disc-light-comes-on-when-pressing-keys-in-iceweasel-preferences-is-this-malevol).

But when I use `cat /proc/kmsg`, the output doesn't always seem to update on
screen in the way I expect. For example, disc writes don't always appear in the
`/proc/kmsg` output when I expect them, and sometimes seemingly not at all. (I
understand that RAM has to be written to disc before disc I/O appears in
`/prog/kmsg`.)

Also the timestamps in the output seem to be 8 minutes behind what they should
be. I want to use the timestamps.

My question is:

Is syslogd (a daemon that's running on my laptop) clashing with
`cat /proc/kmsg`, and causing the above 2 effects? (See reference to syslog(2)
in Full Details, 5.)

If so, can I safely turn off syslogd temporarily, while I use `cat /proc/kmsg`?

Also, what does syslogd do, and do I actually need it (I'm just using Linux on
a single laptop as a single user, in multi-user mode.)?

---

#### Full Details

1. Before doing `cat /proc/kmsg`, I turn off `klogd` to stop loads of unwanted
   messages going to `/proc/kmsg`. And I enable `block_dump` with
   `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump`.
2. To do a test, I have `cat /proc/kmsg` running in one terminal, then from
   another terminal I perform a disc write with `echo 1 > somefile`. I make sure
   `somefile` doesn't already contain `1`.
3. When the arrangement is behaving, `cat /proc/kmsg` displays a line in
   response to my disc write, such as:

   ```
   <7>[ 5685.914279] bash(4413): dirtied inode 460058 (somefile) on sda6
   ```

But sometimes, no such line appears, even when I then type `sync` in the
other terminal (to cause RAM to be written to disc).

4. I understand that a) the number at the left of the `/proc/kmsg` line is time
   since boot (eg the 5685.914279), and that b) the number is seconds.microseconds.
   But when I do a calculation on the seconds figure, the resulting time since boot
   is 8 minutes behind what it should be.
5. In `man proc`, I noticed the following info that I've put in capitals:

   > /proc/kmsg
   >
   > This file can be used instead of the syslog(2) system call to read kernel
   >   messages. A process must have superuser privileges to read this file, and only
   >   one process should read this file. THIS FILE SHOULD NOT BE READ IF A SYSLOG
   >   PROCESS IS RUNNING WHICH USES THE syslog(2) SYSTEM CALL FACILITY TO LOG KERNEL
   >   MESSAGES. Information in this file is retrieved with the dmesg(1) program."

   So this is the reason for my MAIN QUESTION about is `syslogd` causing
   `cat /proc/kmsg` not to behave? I'm a relative novice, so I don't know what
   syslog(2) is, or what it does.

Comment: *"time since boot"* -> Note that does NOT include time spent in sleep or hibernation.  It's not wall clock duration, it's the amount of time the system has been actually running.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dmesg` instead of `cat /proc/kmsg` to read messages generated by the kernel.

syslogd (or klogd) depending on the type of syslog package installed on your system, does indeed use /proc/kmsg as a data source. It then logs those messages (and loggin messages from other programs) to spool files in /var/log.

You can check your syslog config for the relevant files and locations. See `/etc/syslog.conf`, `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, or IIRC, `/etc/syslog-ng.conf`